# GeoJSON: line connecting features

Tags: geojson

How do I create a line connecting Features in GeoJSON? I hope to avoid having to re-enter coordinates for the polylines I use to connect the Features separately...

Comment: Are you writing GeoJSON by hand (i.e. in a text editor)? Or are you using a GIS? Please expand on your question.

Comment: I am using [geojson.io](http://www.geojson.io). To flesh out my question: if I create two `Point`s, and want a `PolyLine` to connect them, is my only choice specifying the coordinates of each `Point` again, or is there a way I can refer back to them?

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean like showing  track points?
There is a free REST API for this

Simply POST GeoJson Data to an endpoint, and view the POI in Geojson(track), GPX(track and route) ,KML, ARML supported app in real time.

https://www.mashape.com/geokoala/geokoala/overview

Just create an AppKey, and check out the code samples in curl,java,node,php,python,objective-c,ruby, and .net.

After posting a few GeoJson:(format can be gpx,kml,geojson )

http://api.reaperfire.com/reaperfire/rest/v1/public/accounts/393233d9-7997-4649-8291-73102d4b7358/tracking/events/2404129838?format=geojson&type=track